# Loop for subsetting higher than and lower than values in a data frame using values from different data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and I have a question I'd like to ask you guys!

I have a large data frame with TimeStamps from an eyetracking experiment.

> `Blockquote ParticipantName RecordingTimestamp GazeEventType GazeEventDuration AOI[Prob]Hit AOI[Prob 2]Hit
>   1               1              -1255                              NA           NA             NA
>   2               1              -1252      Fixation               933           NA             NA
>   3               1              -1249      Fixation               933           NA             NA
>   4               1              -1245      Fixation               933           NA             NA
>   5               1              -1242      Fixation               933           NA             NA
>   6               1              -1239      Fixation               933           NA             NA`

I have in another data frame the Event triggers. I've manipulated them and now I have two columns, one with the start time and the other with the finish time.

> `Blockquote ParticipantName TimeStamp Event EventFinish
>   1               1      6593    10        4593
>   2               1     27235     2       25235
>   3               1     27392    10       25392
>   4               1     47278     1       45278
>   5               1     47440    10       45440
>   6               1     71857     2       69857`

Where Timestamp is the end of the event and EventFinish is the start (made a confusion with the names there, sorry!)

So, that first data frame has around 140.000 rows and starts at a timestamp of -1255 and goes up to 455251.

I need to get the values from the second data frame and make a subset or filter given that the RecordingTimestamp values of the first data frame is higher than the EventFinish and lower than the Timestamp columns of the second data frame. For each of the 24 rows in the secon data frame.

That way I'd eliminate the rows that are not my epoched data.

I've looke around loops, filters and subsets and I was not able to get it right.

I've tried this code:

```
for(i in 1:EventPP1$TimeStamp){
  for (j in 1:EventPP1$EventFinish){

  test3<- subset(Participant1, Participant1$RecordingTimestamp>=EventPP1$EventFinish[j] & Participant1$RecordingTimestamp<=EventPP1$TimeStamp[i] )
  }
}
```

But R just goes on and on and never gets to a final answer.

I've also tried this code:

```
uniq1<- unique(unlist(EventPP1$TimeStamp)) 
uniq1<- as.data.frame(uniq1)
uniq2<- unique(unlist(EventPP1$EventFinish)) 
uniq2<- as.data.frame(uniq2)
for(i in 1:seq_along(uniq1)){
  for (j in 1:seq_along(uniq2)){

    test3<- filter(Participant1, Participant1$RecordingTimestamp>=uniq2[j] & Participant1$RecordingTimestamp<=uniq1[i] )
  }
}
```

But it only gets my the final pair, not the rest.

Can anyone help me please? That's data only from one participant and I have about 80 more. I think the loop might be the more suitable method.

If anyone know how to solve this I'd appreciate it!

Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop only once, and not over the timestamps but over the lines in your second data frame. For every line you have a value for begin and one for end, and you can flag all data in the first data frame that fall within these limits. If I call your data frames p (for Participant) and E (for Events), and give the columns short names:

```
for (i in 1:length(E$ts)){    # note you loop over the 24 lines only
  p$flag[p$ts>=E$start[i] & p$ts <= E$fin[i]] <-1 # set a flag to 1 for good data
}
p<-p[p$flag==1]   # restrict your data frame to flagged data
```